# Windows 8 mail app unable to pick contact

Tags: email, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8-mail-app

I'm using Windows 8 x64 RTM, but when I open the mail app and compose an email, then pick contact using the "+" button:

[image]

I'm greeted with an error message from people hub:

> This app uses email addresses and none of your contacts have any. Open the People app to add this info to your contacts.

[image]

However I do have contacts that have email addresses:

[image]

How do I properly connect the People app to the Windows Mail App?

Comment: Can you please phrase this in the form of a question?

Comment: @imgen:  I have made major edits to your question in order to clarify what's going on and also to make it a question.  Feel free to edit/remove/or roll back the edits as you see fit.

Comment: It's very kind of you to improve my question. I should have put more thought into this question. It's great. I reckon that you are having the same issue as I do:)

Comment: @imgen yes I am.  Be interested to see what's the issue.

Comment: @KronoS I cracked up when I saw Ivo's disturbingly cheerful grin :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that [this is a bug within the software](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1111289-mail-app-update-cant-find-contacts/).  The current fix is to uninstall and the re-install the Mail, People, Calendar, and Messaging App.

Before Uninstalling be sure to sync all your settings: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> -> Setting -> Change PC Settings -> Sync Your Settings.  Set all to be "on"

To Uninstall the App, right click (or Long press hold) on any of the apps (Mail, Calendar, People, Messaging) and then selecting uninstall:

[image]

You'll be prompted to uninstall, just select "Uninstall" again:

[image]

Finally, open the App Store, and then search for "Mail".  The first option is the "Mail, People, Message, and Calendar" app combo.  Install it.

[image]

You'll have to wait for a few mins (about 5 for me) for all of the contacts, settings, and such to download and sync.  After that, the problem is resolved.